# What is the difference between these two functions using async/await/TPL?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I think I have successfully confused myself for the day.

```
public void DoSomething1()
{
    Task.Delay(1000);
}

public async void DoSomething2()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

What is the difference between these two functions in terms of what happens within them when they are called? What is the purpose of using an `async` method that does not return a `Task`?

Comment: Both of these methods successfully do nothing, equally well.  These two methods are identical to `public void DoSomething3(){}` (outside of the fact that those two will consume a handful of CPU cycles in accomplishing nothing).

Comment: Does the `Task.Delay` not run at all in either?

Comment: It runs.  It accomplishes nothing.  Both methods are saying, "Do nothing one second from now" which is identical to just saying, "do nothing".

Comment: If I were to call either of these functions, would there be any difference in calling one or the other?

Comment: How does my first comment not answer that question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the difference between these two functions in terms of what happens within them when they are called?

`DoSomething1` is a synchronous method. As such:

- It starts an asynchronous delay *and then ignores it*.
- Any exceptions from the asynchronous delay are silently ignored.
- Any exceptions from `DoSomething` are raised directly to the caller.

`DoSomething2` is an asynchronous `void` method. As such:

- It starts an asynchronous delay *and then observes it*.
- Any exceptions from the asynchronous delay are re-raised on the `SynchronizationContext` that was current at the time `DoSomething2` started executing. This generally results in program termination.
- Any exceptions from `DoSomething2` are also raised on that `SynchronizationContext`, with the same result.

> What is the purpose of using an async method that does not return a Task?

`async void` is not a natural thing. For example, the equivalent simply does not exist in F#. `async void` was added to C#/VB to enable event handlers to become asynchronous without changing the entire event handling or delegation system.

In short, you should avoid `async void`, and only use them for event handlers (or logical equivalents to event handlers, like `ICommand.Execute` in MVVM).

Comment: Thank you, I think this cleared it up for me. And my good nights sleep too.