# What's the difference between awaiting async Task function and calling await inside a void function?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

To understand the question please take a look on the `await` calls and the definition of the function `InitSyncContext()` of the following example.

Based on that i would like to know how the program will behave on each scenario because i don't fully understand what´s the difference between calling `await InitSyncContext(store)` and having a `await` call inside without returning a `Task`.

For reference i did a research before and i found a similar [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023696/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-functions-using-async-await-tpl) however i think it's different in my case.

*The following code is a simplified example from a real world code just for demonstration purposes.

```
void Main()
{
    Initializer();
}

private async void Initializer()
{
    var store = InitLocalStore();
    await InitSyncContext(store); // <-- Here, await call
    InitFileSync(store);
}

// Here returns Task (without having a return inside. No compile errors)
private async Task InitSyncContext(MobileServiceSQLiteStore store)
{
    await Client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
}

//------------- Second Method -------------

void Main()
{
    Initializer();
}

private void Initializer()
{
    var store = InitLocalStore();
    InitSyncContext(store); // <-- Here without await call
    InitFileSync(store);
}

// Here is void but with a async call inside
private async void InitSyncContext(MobileServiceSQLiteStore store)
{
    await Client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
}
```

Comment: You can't use the await keyword inside a non-async method. It's not valid grammar in the C# language. This doesn't compile

Comment: @SteveCooper thanks for point it out. I corrected the example. This code is taken from a real world code (but without the Main definition) so i can test it. This way compiles.

Comment: _"[Prefer async Task methods over async void methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)"_

Comment: @MickyD - stick this as an answer. I'll upvote...

Comment: @SteveCooper Done. Thanks :)

Comment: @CodeArtist rather than simply posting so link only answers, I actually explained it here. I hope this clears things up, thank you for taking the time to ask this on SO.

Comment: @CodeArtist Your problem here is with the mobile app's `App.App()` constructor, am I right? Not `Main()` as in your example? If so, does it work the same as for a console app?

Comment: @hbob actually yes that was the problem but my question was specifically on how will behave `await` in a similar environment (not necessarily using Xamarin but C#). To use the `await` in class constructor method i implemented the factory pattern described here http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html and i haven't tried to use Xamarin in console apps.

Comment: @CodeArtist Yep that works very well, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the difference between awaiting `async Task` function and calling `await` inside a `void` function?

The whole world! Everything...and then some. Let's take a step back and start with some of the basics.

You should go "async all the way", i.e.; if you're returning an *awaitable* (`Task` or `Task<T>`) these should correctly use the `async` and `await` keywords.

There are several things that need to be clarified here. You should not have `async void` methods, instead you should have `async Task` - the exception being event handlers (where the delegates are predefined as non-task returning) and the like. Let's examine and pick apart method one (I'm going to ignore the `Main` entry points):

**One**

```
private async void Initializer()
{
    var store = InitLocalStore();
    await InitSyncContext(store); // <-- Here, await call
    ...
}

// Here returns Task (without having a return inside. No compile errors)
private async Task InitSyncContext(MobileServiceSQLiteStore store)
{
    await Client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
}
```

You have an `Initializer` method that is immediately a code smell as it is `async void`. This should be `async Task` and it should have the "Async" suffix. Additionally, you have an `InitSyncContext` that takes on a `store` variable and invokes some client initialization work. The code smell here is that you are using `async` and `await`. This is not need on simple (single task) workloads like this. Instead you should simply use the `return` keyword. Example at the very bottom. Let's look at method two:

**Two**

```
private void Initializer()
{
    var store = InitLocalStore();
    InitSyncContext(store); // <-- Here without await call
    ...
}

// Here is void but with a async call inside
private async void InitSyncContext(MobileServiceSQLiteStore store)
{
    await Client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
}
```

Things have officially gone from bad to worse! With the misconceptions of the asynchronous nomenclatures, we have assumed that since one method appeared to work "ok" without taking into account the best practices that another method could follow suit. You made the `InitSyncContext` method `async void`. The reason methods should not be `async void` is that they are fire-and-forget. The internal async state machine doesn't have a `Task` to latch onto and therefore the state is lost. When you remove the caller's `await` you are saying start this asynchronous operation but you do not care about it's results.

Here is the correct way to implement the desired functionality:

**Correct**

```
private async Task InitializerAsync()
{
    var store = InitLocalStore();
    await InitSyncContextAsync(store);
    ...
}

// Simply return the task that represents the async operation and let the caller await it
private Task InitSyncContextAsync(MobileServiceSQLiteStore store)
{
    return Client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
}
```

*A note about the `Main` method from your snippets, if this is part of a console application - the top-level entry point into your async stack would invoke either `.Result` or `.Wait()`.*

Further reading

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: When you said "top-level entry point into your async stack would invoke either .Result or .Wait()" do you mean that one needs to do something special in `Main()`? What would that be? If we go "async all the way", how do you deal with the fact that `Main` is not async?

Comment: @hbob, yes. since `Main` is invoking an `async` method chain, we need to ensure that we call `.Wait()` on it. Of course assuming that this is a console application.

Comment: Oh you mean inside the console's `Main` function (as in OP's example) we would do `InitializerAsync().Wait()` and that would make it "async all the way"? (That would be blocking though, but I guess that makes sense so the app doesnt exit.)

Comment: @hbob Right, in console applications there is no native support for `async` at the entry point of the application. Think about it, if you're on the command line and attempting to invoke the `.exe` it doesn't know what a `Task` is. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9212343/2410379) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17630538/2410379) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

> What's the difference between awaiting async Task function and calling await inside a void function?

This is perhaps a very big question is best served by reading the fine article *[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)* by Mr Stephen Cleary.

Some summary points:

> Avoid async void - Prefer async Task methods over async void methods

[image]

### See also

- Cleary, S, *"Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming"*, March 2013, Microsoft, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, retrieved 14/7/2016

Comment: Suggest adding summary of answers found at the referenced sites

Answer (score -1):

In first example compiler generate something like this:

```
TheadPool.RunTask(()=>InitSyncContext(store)).ContinueWith(()=>InitFileSync(store))
```

At second — nothing interesting. Because nobody wait the end of the task. All calls will be in main thread exept await Client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);

Comment: I know it. It's simplification.